# Most isolated record

Tags: mysql

Consider a MySQL table with a `datetime` field. I would like to select the row with the furtherest time between it to between the next or previous `datetime` values. For example, if there exist records with the following values:

```
1   2012-10-17 12:00
2   2012-10-16 12:00
3   2012-10-14 12:00
4   2012-10-08 12:00
5   2012-10-03 12:00
6   2012-10-01 12:00
```

Therefore the most "isolated" record is record #4 as it is 5 days away from the nearest record.

Note that there may or may not be ties for "most isolated", in this case any of the tying rows may be returned, or all of them. Also, although the example shows the records with `datetime` values sequentially ordered, that may not necessarily be true in the real data set.

Comment: By isolated, do you look at the average to the previous and next records, or the smallest of the 2?

Comment: @PinnyM: Actually, either method would be acceptable. I'm interested in seeing how both methods might be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to determine distance to the closest records:

```
SELECT foo.d, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, max(earlier.d), d) as previous, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, d, min(later.d)) as next
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN foo later ON foo.d < later.d
LEFT JOIN foo earlier ON foo.d > earlier.d
GROUP BY foo.d
```

You can get the farthest of these values fairly easily.

Comment: Thank you, the `JOIN` on 'less than' is quite clever! I will play around with this and get back shortly.

Answer (score 3):

If your table is defined like foo (id, time) you can use the following sql:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM foo t2
   INNER JOIN foo t1 ON t1.id=t2.id+1
   INNER JOIN foo t3 ON t3.id=t1.id+1
  WHERE timestampdiff(day,t1.time,t2.time)+timestampdiff(day,t3.time,t1.time)=
    (SELECT max(timestampdiff(day,t1.time,t2.time)+timestampdiff(day,t3.time,t1.time))
         FROM foo t2 INNER JOIN foo t1 ON t1.id=t2.id+1 
                     INNER JOIN foo t3 ON t3.id=t1.id+1)
```

to get all the "most isolated" entries. If you need only one entry, you can always add a `limit 1`.
Also note that here we are assuming that the entries are ordered by timestamp. If the entries are not ordered by time you can create a view that will order them.

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa873/1)